# ToolTips on horizontal imagebutton list on tapping fast

Tags: android, tooltip

(I am sorry for my English/Explanation).
I want to create a tooltip for one of my app.
In this i required a **tooltip for dynamic horizontal-list of imagebuttons** .
I have done this using [one of tutorial](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/), but my problem is that
i have to tap/click/touch twice if already showing tooltip.
But i need fast touch response from each and every buttons.(Means In every tab/click of each buttons it hide previous and show the tooltip for current button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by changing value to false of method from class popup window
 Now its working fine.. thanks

```
mWindow.setTouchable(false);
```